# Outlook (Office JS) desktop authenticating user using EWS

Tags: outlook, office365, office-2016

How do I authenticate my (desktop) user to a local Outlook exchange server using EWS when posting a Service Request without manually inputting my network credentials via the NetworkCredential class? is this only possible via Office365 online (Non desktop)?